# How to extend query by one more parameter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to list authors and their books. Does this query look right? Because it lists same books for every author, I dont know if its database issue or my query.

Also, how can I extend this query to display category of each book?

`author` has `name, surname, author_id`

`book` has `title, book_id, category_id`

`book_author` has `id, author_id, book_id`

`category` has `category_id, name`

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.title
FROM author a, book b, book_author c
WHERE c.author_id =  a.author_id
```

Comment: First rule is to use proper `join` syntax! It's been the standard for about 30 years. [Bad habbits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: As Stu says ^ Also, you'll need to join **book** on **book_author** as well as joining **author**. Also, I'd remove the **book_author.id** column and make **author_id, book_id** a composite key. You'll want that to be unique and indexed anyway, and the separate **id** column is just cruft.

Comment: The query does not look write because it has commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include a join condition for the book table, so every book is being matched with every author row. You could fix this by adding another condition:

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.title
FROM author a, book b, book_author c
WHERE c.author_id = a.author_id
AND c.book_id = b.book_id
```

But as Stu says, using proper join syntax will make this much clearer:

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.title
FROM author a
JOIN book_author ba ON (a.author_id = ba.author_id)
JOIN book b ON (b.book_id = ba.book_id)
```

At this point, it should hopefully be clear how to include the category as well:

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.title, c.name as category_name
FROM author a
JOIN book_author ba ON (a.author_id = ba.author_id)
JOIN book b ON (b.book_id = ba.book_id)
JOIN category c ON (c.category_id = b.category_id)
```